# How do I fill the image with white?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create a rotated image which is white, but this does not work.
The image always turns out black.

How could I achieve this?

```
def rotate_image(image):
    # Convert the image to a NumPy array
    image_array = np.array(image)

    # Set the fill color (RGB format)
    fill_color = (255, 255, 255)  # White color

    # Define the rotation angle
    rotation_angle = random.randint(1, 360)

    # Perform rotation using OpenCV
    rows, cols = image_array.shape[:2]
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols / 2, rows / 2), rotation_angle, 1)
    rotated_array = cv2.warpAffine(image_array, M, (cols, rows), borderValue=fill_color)
    
    # Convert the rotated array back to an image
    rotated_image = Image.fromarray(rotated_array)

    # Save the rotated image as a PNG file
    rotated_image.save("test1.png")
    
    return rotated_image
```

[image]

Here is the code that I am using it in:

```
def get_dataset_batch(batch_size=2):
    flip = False
    base_image = Image.open("star_map_base.png")
    train_A = []
    train_B = []
    
    for i in range(0, batch_size):
        if flip:
            turbulence_size = random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4])
            turbulence_image = Image.open("turbulence.jpg")
            x = random.randint(0, 4096 - IMG_SIZE * turbulence_size)
            y = random.randint(0, 2136 - IMG_SIZE * turbulence_size)
            crop_actual_rect = (x, y, x + IMG_SIZE * turbulence_size, y + IMG_SIZE * turbulence_size)
            cropped_actual = turbulence_image.crop(crop_actual_rect)
            cropped_actual = cropped_actual.resize((IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
        else:
            helix_size = random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
            helix_image = Image.open("helix_bw_base.jpg")
            x = random.randint(0, 4096 - IMG_SIZE * helix_size)
            y = random.randint(0, 4096 - IMG_SIZE * helix_size)
            crop_actual_rect = (x, y, x + IMG_SIZE * helix_size, y + IMG_SIZE * helix_size)
            cropped_actual = helix_image.crop(crop_actual_rect)
            cropped_actual = cropped_actual.resize((IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
        
        flip = not flip

        cropped_actual = cropped_actual.convert('LA')

        star_overlayed = cropped_actual
        star_overlayed = rotate_image(star_overlayed)
        star_overlayed = star_overlayed.convert('L')
        star_overlayed = Image.fromarray(transform(image=np.asarray(star_overlayed))["image"] / 1)
        star_overlayed = star_overlayed.convert('LA')

        ca = star_overlayed.copy()
        ca = ca.convert('L')
        
        base_image = base_image.convert('RGBA')
        star_overlayed = star_overlayed.convert('RGBA')
        overlaid_image = overlay_images(star_overlayed, base_image)
        overlaid_image = Image.fromarray(overlaid_image)
        
        star_overlayed = overlaid_image.convert('L')
        a = np.asarray(ca, dtype="float32").reshape(1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1) / 512
        b = np.asarray(star_overlayed, dtype="float32").reshape(1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1) / 512
        train_A.append(a)
        train_B.append(b)
    
    return train_A, train_B
```

Comment: Please ensure your question is *minimal* and complete so it has the necessary input images, and complete and minimal code that is runnable. A mock-up of the expected output image would be useful too. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that your source image actually contains useful information. It appears to be entirely black already.

By the way, your source image appears to have a 4th channel, an alpha channel. Giving the `borderValue` incompletely results in the remaining value being 0. That's why the out-of-range pixels become transparent.

Simply setting `borderValue` is insufficient. You need to also set the border ***mode*** flag of `warpAffine()`.

`BORDER_CONSTANT` uses the `borderValue` you provide.

`BORDER_REPLICATE` uses the nearest valid source pixel for any destination pixel.

You should also stick to using one library consistently, not mix them both. OpenCV is perfectly capable of reading and writing image files. To get the image *with* alpha channel, you just need to pass the right flag.

Answer (score 1):

Try [flood-filling](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gaf1f55a048f8a45bc3383586e80b1f0d0) the rectangle with white **before** applying the rotation. Use the center of the figure/image as seed point:

```
# Read the image:
imagePath = "D://opencvImages//blackRect.png"
inputImage = cv2.imread(imagePath)

# Set seed:
random.seed(42)

# Get image dimensions:
(imageHeight, imageWidth) = inputImage.shape[:2]

# Get center coordinates:
xCenter = int(0.5 * imageWidth)
yCenter = int(0.5 * imageHeight)

# Flood fill at center:
center = (xCenter, yCenter)
whiteColor = (255, 255, 255)
cv2.floodFill(inputImage, None, center, whiteColor)

# Show filled image:
cv2.imshow("Filled Image", inputImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Define the rotation angle
rotation_angle = random.randint(1, 360)

# Perform rotation using OpenCV
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((imageWidth / 2, imageHeight / 2), rotation_angle, 1)
rotatedImage = cv2.warpAffine(inputImage, M, (imageWidth, imageHeight), borderValue=(0, 0, 0))

# Show rotated image:
cv2.imshow("Rotated Image", rotatedImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the progression - Input image (black rectangle) -> Filled image (white rectangle) -> Rotated image:
[image]